# What is the code that one can use for country-specific ranking search on Baidu?

Tags: search-engine

What is the code that one can use for country-specific ranking searches on Baidu?

In other words, how can I make Baidu search engine ignore where I am in the world?

For Google, the code to use is https://www.google.com/?gl=us&gws_rd=ssl.

How about for Baidu?